# Posting form to PHP receive 500 error (Internal server error)

Tags: php, html, regex, mysqli

The progress generates a 500 Internal Server Error on the site of the PHP file (vip_reg.php), I simplified and remove some redundant codes/comments but still get the 500 error. Once I made invalid data (invalid phone number/invalid format of email) and post to server, it shows nothing and stopped on php page. Does the mysqli statement crash the program, or HTML is not well-structured?

I'm a very beginner in PHP and mysqli, I am sorry if it is a dumb question.
So, any hint or suggestion will be very appreciated and grateful.
Thanks all.

HTML file:

```
          ......<div class='rows'>
                    <div class='col_left'>
                        <img src='imageabc.jpg' id='left_img' alt='test'>
                    </div>
                    <form action="vip_reg.php" method="POST"><!--Post data to PHP-->
                    <div class='col_right'>

                        <p><span class="txtDesc">Your Name</span><span class="txtField"><input type='text' name='vipName' id='vipName' size='40' autocomplete="off" /></span></p> <?php echo $errorMsg; ?><br/><br/>
                        <p><span class="txtDesc">Phone Number</span><span class="txtField"><input type='tel' name='telNum' id='telNum' size='40' maxlength='8' autocomplete="off"/></span></p><?php echo $errorTel; ?><br/><br/>
                        <p><span class="txtDesc">Email Address </span><span class="txtField"><input type='text' name='email' id='email' size='40' autocomplete="off"/></span></p><?php echo $errEmail; ?><br/><br/>
                        <p><span class="txtDesc">Car Number</span><span class="txtField"><input type='text' name='carNum' id='carNum' size='40' autocomplete="off"/></span></span></p><?php echo $errCarNum; ?><br/><br/>
                        <p><span class="txtDesc">Verification</span><span class="txtField"><span class='g-recaptcha' data-sitekey='xxxxxxxx Google recaptcha-secret-key'></span></span></p><?php echo $errorMsg; ?><br/>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='rows'>
                    <div class='button_Style'>
                        <input type="image" name="submit" id="submit"src="image/submit_btn.jpg" alt="submit" /> 
                    </div>
                </form>......
```

PHP file:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if(!empty($_POST['vipName'])&& !empty($_POST['telNum'])&& !empty($_POST['email']&& !empty($_POST['carNum']))){
        if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){  //detect user clicks recaptcha or not
            $recaptcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
            include("getCurlData.php");
            $google_url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
            $secret='google-secret-key';
            $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $url=$google_url."?secret=".$secret."&response=".$recaptcha."&remoteip=".$ip;
            $res=getCurlData($url);
            $res= json_decode($res, true);

            if($res['success']){ //Get POST Data
                $name_vip = htmlspecialchars($_POST['vipName']);
                $telNumber = htmlspecialchars($_POST['telNum']);
                $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
                $carNum = htmlspecialchars($_POST['carNum']);

                //validation
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT car_num FROM vip_register WHERE username='$carNum'");
                    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){ //unique
                        $errorCarNum = "The Car Plate Number is existed, please check.";
                        return true;
                    }elseif(strlen($telNumber)!=8){
                        $errTel = "Telephone number must be 8 digits.";
                        return false;
                    }elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { //validate email
                        $errEmail = "The format of Email address is invalid.";
                        return false;
                    }else{ //success
                        echo "OK";
                        $vip = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['$name_vip']);
                        $tel = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['telNumber']);
                        $emailAddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['$email']);
                        $carNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['$carNum']);
                        //insert into DB    
                        $sql_vip="INSERT INTO `vip_register` (`name`, `tel`, `email`, `car_num`) VALUES ('$vip', '$tel', '$emailAddress', '$carNumber')";
                        $uploadSQL = $dbConn->prepare($sql_vip);
                        $uploadSQL->execute();
                        //clear the error msg
                        $name_vip = $telNumber = $email = $carNum = "";
                        $errorMsg = $errTel = $errEmail = $errCarNum = "";
                        //turn it to success page
                        //header("Location:xxx.php");
                    }


        }
    }else{
        $errorMsg = $errTel = $errEmail = $errCarNum = "It should not be blank.";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the server's error logs?  PHP's *usually* pretty good about telling you what's broken.

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` RTM on that function. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Then you're using `mysqli_query($con` <<< and `$uploadSQL = $dbConn` <<< so, which one is it? `$con` or `$dbConn`?

Comment: Then you made a typo `$eamilAddress` - `'$emailAddress'` - This question is a classic "debug" question. Check for errors; you have many. You're not doing that. `$telNumber` and using `'$tel'`??? same for quite a few others.

Comment: Here; visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php then apply that to your code.

Comment: Yes, I checked error.log after checking everytime. I am confused why the server appears 500 error.

Comment: Are you checking the right error logs?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at your PHP error log for the specific error you are getting in your code.

This is good practice to get into, while coding, in general.

You can either add the PHP function:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to the very top of your PHP file...

Or (and this is the better option for a live environment) ... Go into the commandline for your server - if you have access to the command line - and type the following command:

```
grep error_log /etc/php.ini
```

This will output, in the command prompt, the location of your PHP error log.

Locate that file and download/open that file, to see the latest error you are getting. Paste that error here and we all can help you resolve that error better.

Answer (score 0):

500 server error comes from Apache, not PHP. It means "server is mis-configured" In my experience, it is always due to something in a .htaccess file that your version of Apache doesn't understand.

Use a text editor and comment all lines in .htaccess file, wait a moment and test your script. If it works, start uncommenting lines, one section at a time in the .htaccess file until you get a 500 error again.

Note some web hosts don't seem to see changes in .htaccess file right away.